# Firestore show loading indicator while fetching data

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the data of a user from the Cloud Firestore database and display it in a Fragment. Since the querying in Firestore works asynchronously the UI gets loaded before all the data has been fetched from the Firestore DB. The `OnViewCreated` method of my fragment loads null data if the querying is not fast enough.

What is the best practice to avoid this issue? Should I be showing a loading indicator while the querying is being processed? If so, how do I know when it is finished?

Also, what is the best practice for retrieving the data in my `User` class and sharing the same instance among the different fragments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use `addOnCompleteListener` when trying to get a document from a Cloud Firestore database. This means that `onComplete()` method is triggered and becuase it has an asynchronous behaviour you must call another method or directly display the UI elements inside that method, otherwise it will always be `null`.

There is another approach, to add a callback in order to be able to access it outside that method as well. For that, i recomand dive into asynchronous world and see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange). This is for getting the data outside `onDataChange()` method but it is almost the same.

For the best user experience, you can add a loading indicator so user cannot see a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why `addOnCompleteListener` instead of `addOnSuccessListener`? Also if you could include a comment abouot my last question that would be great.

Comment: Because `addOnCompleteListener` is called when the Task completes, in which moment you need to display the UI elements. In the same way you do with activities, you need to do with fragments.